# Unlist to dataframe where each vector is a new column

Tags: r

I create a list, then I try to create a dataframe from this list, however I would like each new instance of the list to be a new colum. In the below example, I have a list with 2 levels, first, a,b,c, second, 1,2,3. I would like a dataframe that comes back with

```
l <- list(c("a", "b", "c"), c(1,2,3))
df <- as.data.frame(unlist(l))

1  2

a  1
b  2
c  3
```

at the moment I get

```
1
a
b
c
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `data.frame` or `as.data.frame`, it directly gives you dataframe with 2 columns.

```
data.frame(l)
```

Add proper names using `setNames`.

```
setNames(data.frame(l), paste0('col', seq_along(l)))

#  col1 col2
#1    a    1
#2    b    2
#3    c    3
```

Comment: Okay, that was embarrassingly easy. Thanks so much, just trying things with lists since they are faster.

Comment: Okay, that was embarrassingly easy. Thanks so much, just trying things with lists since they are faster.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `deframe/enframe`

```
library(tibble)
deframe(l) %>%
    enframe
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  name  value
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 a         1
#2 b         2
#3 c         3
```

---

Or with `setDT`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(l)[]
#   V1 V2
#1:  a  1
#2:  b  2
#3:  c  3
```